# What are these objects inside enum?

Tags: rust

In Rust documentation, there's a page on [destructuring enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/destructuring/destructure_enum.html), and it has the code like this:

```
enum Color {
    Red,
    // skipped some code
    RGB(u32, u32, u32)
    HSV(u32, u32, u32),
    HSL(u32, u32, u32),
    // more code skipped
}
```

I wonder what syntax `RGB(u32, etc)` is called, and what type Color::RGB is. Debug-printing it only raises exception that gives only partial understanding:

```
println!("{:?}", Color::RGB);
```

Result:

```
error[E0277]: `fn(u32, u32, u32) -> Color {Color::RGB}` doesn't implement `Debug`
  --> src/main.rs:40:22
   |
40 |     println!("{:?}", Color::RGB);
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^ `fn(u32, u32, u32) -> Color {Color::RGB}` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `Debug`
   |
   = help: the trait `Debug` is not implemented for `fn(u32, u32, u32) -> Color {Color::RGB}`
```

Reading this I assume Color::RGB is a function that produces... Color::RGB -- itself?!

Comment: `Reading this I assume Color::RGB is a function, but it produces...` - it's a tuple, https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.tuple.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Color::RGB` is both a function that returns a `Color` instance and a variant of the `Color` enum, which means it can be used in pattern matching. This kind of function is usually called a "constructor" for the enum variant.

This can be seen using the usual trick to get the type of something:

```
enum Color {
    Red,
    RGB(u32, u32, u32)
}

let foo: () = Color::RGB;
let bar: () = Color::RGB (0, 0, 0);
```

Playground

Gives:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:7:19
  |
7 |     let foo: () = Color::RGB;
  |              --   ^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found fn item
  |              |
  |              expected due to this
  |
  = note: expected unit type `()`
               found fn item `fn(u32, u32, u32) -> Color {Color::RGB}`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:8:19
  |
8 |     let bar: () = Color::RGB(0, 0, 0);
  |              --   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found enum `Color`
  |              |
  |              expected due to this
```

Note that the return value for the `Color::RGB` function is `Color {Color::RGB}` (not simply `Color::RGB`), meaning that it returns a value of type `Color` that always contains the `Color::RGB` variant.

Answer (score 3):

Rust enums are algebraic data types. It means they can contain information within them.

Each of the variants are constructors.
In the example `Color::Rgb` is a constructor for the `Color` enum type. It takes 3 `u32` and returns a `Color` instance of the `Rgb` variant.

Variants can be pattern matched and also its internal components:

```rust
match Color::Rgb(10, 10, 10) {
    ...
    Color::Rgb(r, g, b) => { println!("{} {} {}", r, g, b) }
}
```